# $rootScope.$emit not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, emit

I'm trying to emit event in AngularJS into second controller using:

**First Controller:**

```
    $scope.checkThemeContent = function(theme) {
    console.log("Trying to get cards for theme id: " +theme.id);
    console.log(theme);

    $scope.selectedTheme = theme;

    if(theme.count_of_cards >0) {
        //$scope.$emit('detailDisplayed', {});
        $scope.displayedTemplate = 'detail';
        $rootScope.$emit('detailDisplayed', {});
    } else {
        $scope.displayedTemplate = 'empty';
    }
};
```

**Second controller:**

```
 $rootScope.$on('detailDisplayed', function(event, args) {
        alert('Received');
        $scope.initDataGrid();
    });
```

But event is not triggered.

I tried to used scope in reverse direction and it works.

Where can be problem please?

I followed this tutorial:

http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the event being emitted before the `$on` handler is attached?

Comment: if this is working in reverse, maybe you are doing an emit before defining the listener Edit: Same that @someKittens says

Comment: It would be very helpful if you created a JSFiddle or Plunkr example.

Comment: Durp, you're at rootScope u can't emit higher

Comment: $emit-ing along the $rootScope is definitely okay and in most cases is deemed faster than propagating up or down through the directives/components

Answer (score 9):

> I tried to used scope in reverse direction and it works.

Sounds to me like your code is structured to where the event is emitted before the `$on` handler is attached to `$rootScope`.  Make sure the second controller has been instantiated before emitting the event.

Comment: Hello, what do You exactly mean " instantiated before emitting the event." please?

Comment: @redrom you need to make sure the second controller is listening for the event before you emit it.

Comment: And how can i check this please?

Comment: Create an example on JSFiddle for us to see

Answer (score 3):

Remember: emit goes up the prototype chain, broadcast goes down. If you are already at the top (i.e. `$rootScope`) it can't go any higher. Use `$broadcast` to get the event to fire across the board.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('detailDisplayed');
```

Check this article:

https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/04/08/refactoring-angularjs-get-hands-filthy/

Comment: It is not relevant here because the event is sent and received on `$rootScope`.

Comment: This actually helped me.  $emit wasn't working. Changed to $broadcast.  And I'm using $rootScope